# Pointwise convergence of Random walk to the Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $\{X_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables taking value in the set $\{-1,1\}$ with $P(X_i = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$.
Let $S_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$, and for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ define the random process $B^k$ as
$$
B^k(t) = \frac{S_{[kt]}}{\sqrt{k}} \qquad t \in \mathbb{R} 
$$

where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$.

I know that $(B^k(t))_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ converges to the standard Brownian motion in distribution, does it also converges pointwise? i.e. is there a random process $\{B(t)\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ so that
$$
\forall t \in \mathbb{R} \quad  \lim_{k \to \infty} B^k(t) = B(t) \quad \text{a.s}
$$
and further that $B(t)$ is the Brownian motion.

Comment: If the pointwise limit exists, then it must be BM. So the question really is if the limit exists.

Comment: A related question seems to be : is there pointwise convergence in the central limit theorem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't.  By the Kolmogorov 0-1 law, if the a.s. (or even i.p.) limit exists, it is a constant, which is absurd.

To see this, let's take $t=1$ for simplicity.  Suppose that $S_k / \sqrt{k} \to Y$ a.s.  Fix $j$ and write, for $k \ge j$,

$$\frac{S_k}{\sqrt{k}} = \frac{X_1 + \dots + X_{j-1}}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{X_{j} + \dots + X_k}{\sqrt{k}}$$

As $k \to \infty$, the first term goes to zero a.s. (since the numerator does not depend on $k$).  So we have

$$Y = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{X_{j} + \dots + X_k}{\sqrt{k}}$$

which shows that $Y \in \sigma(X_j, X_{j+1}, \dots)$.  But $j$ was arbitrary, so this shows that $Y$ is a tail random variable.  Kolmogorov says the tail $\sigma$-field is almost trivial, meaning that $Y$ is a.s. equal to a constant.

Alternatively, the law of the iterated logarithm for random walk will also show you that, almost surely, $\limsup S_k / \sqrt{k} = +\infty$ and $\liminf S_k / \sqrt{k} = -\infty$.

Comment: What is *fun* is that Steven Shreve explicitly pretends having constructed the Brownian motion as the limit of these scaled symmetric random walks in Stochastic Calculus for Finance II in 3.1.1. Page 93.

Comment: Can I quote this result in a paper? Should I reference it as a post on MSE?

Comment: @JanStuller: You certainly can if you like; there's a cite button under the post to generate a bibtex entry.  But I feel like it is pretty well known that there cannot be pointwise convergence in the CLT - as in my last line, that's in some ways the main point of the LIL.

Comment: @Olórin: To be fair to Shreve, he just says "We obtain Brownian motion as the limit of the scaled random walks $W^{(n)}(t)$ of (3.2.7) as $n \to \infty$".  He doesn't say "pointwise limit" and he presumably means "limit in distribution", which is quite correct.  (Anyway, I think it's more of an offhand comment than a mathematical claim: the convergence in distribution of the process, i.e. Donsker's theorem or functional CLT, is not formally stated or proved in the book.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this but if you allow constructing $B^k$ with different copies of i.i.d. random variables, then by Skorokhod's representation theorem you can find a space such that the point-wise convergence hold (for different $B^k$ the $X_i$ are different).

Comment: see Theorem 13.8 in Breiman's book "Probability" for a nice self-contained presentation.